# Cycles in the Chow ring of the moduli of curves coming from Hurwitz theory

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, mapping-class-groups, gromov-witten-theory, hurwitz-theory

Are there interesting cycles (other then the famous ones such as: Harris and Mumford's gonality divisor, the Gieseker-Petri divisor [which can be realized as the branch locus of a forgetful map from the space of admissible covers], and the Hain-Pixton double ramification locus) in $A^*(\overline{M}_{g,n})$ coming from Hurwitz theory?

Comment: Kazarian has used the ELSV formula to prove results about the Chow rings of Deligne-Mumford moduli spaces.  Is that what you are asking about?

Comment: The double ramification cycle in $A^g(\overline M_{g,n})$ is certainly an interesting (tautological) cycle, which in some sense "comes" from Hurwitz theory.

Comment: Hi Jason, not exactly (I was thinking more of things like divisors in $\overline{M}_g$ that come from Hurwitz theory), but that sounds interesting. I'll take a look, thanks!

Comment: Hi Andrea, yes the double ramification cycle is one such example ... it's actually the only one I heard of :-) I was wondering if there are others (maybe more classical?)